# copying roaming profile credential file of another computer

Tags: windows, windows-dpapi, credentials

I am trying to recover login information of another computer. I have managed to copy the local/roaming profile credential files located in C:\users\%username%\APPDATA\local\Microsoft\Credentials\ and C:\users\%username%\APPDATA\roaming\Microsoft\Credentials\

when I try to copy these credential files in my credential store location, the files are automatically deleted. no clue why? I am trying to recover logon credentials from these files I found on my other computer. 
I am looking for an elegant way and I dont know the logon password, and I rather not use any cracking methods.

Comment: Can you share the OS details and other relevant details ? What type of credentials ?

Comment: 1.What credentials are you looking for.?

2. Read this link https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dpapi/nf-dpapi-cryptprotectdata. Usually softwares which stores passwords in this directory use the API CryptProtectData (with revelant flags) so that decryption of credentials is only possible on the computer where the data was encrypted.